# angularjs $state.href returns incorrect URL with custom type object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I came with a strange issue which i am unable to solve after hard work of many hours. Please do help me with these problem.

I have created a route with custom type applied on it

```
$stateProvider.state('root.projects', {
   url: "projects/{filterPath:nonURIEncoded}",
   params: {
     filterPath: {
       value: null,
       squash: true
     }
   }
});
```

The purpose of the custom type "nonURIEncoded" is to treat the trailing slashes in state parameter as the valid url parameter, though this is working fine with routes but gives me incorrect URL with state.href (example given below).

```
$state.href("root.projects", {
  filterPath: "computer-engineering/"
}, {                    
  absolute: true
});
```

It seems state.href encodes the URL parameters and doesn't apply custom type object given to particular ui-state. I am looking for a generic soltuion wherein any custom object applied to ui-state, state.href should return me a url applying custom object to it.

Comment: Have you considered using [decodeUri()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) to fix it?

Comment: I want a generic solution which works for all the custom type object for ui-router, the problem is state.href doesn't work with custom type object. Any complete solution to get the absolute URL of the state or any workaround using state.href?

Comment: Note you are getting the URL ... it's just been URL encoded and you can use `decodeUri()` to, well, decode it.  `%2F` translates to a `/` when it is decoded. This is pretty standard stuff :)

Comment: True, this will solve my issue for particular problem, the whole point of my issue is there should be solution which works for any custom type object applied to ui-router, your solution will not work if i have any other custom type object for ui-router, say for instance i have written a custom type named as "convertSpaceToHyphen" which converts all param space to hyphen, so i expect state.href to return the url with these changes. As per my observation state.href just applies params to the state and returns the url, it doesn't consider any custom type object applied to that particular state.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and state that, instead of saying "expected output" and "actual output". One benefit to editing your question is that it will reappear on the home page and get additional visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.